# How to creating a db in emulator directly

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

How to create a db in emulator directly using the adb command? I don't have any database folder under the data/data section of my application package, hence i won't be able to enter into the database folder and create the db using:

```
SQLite3 myDatabase.db
```

Then how to do it? Please help

Thanks,
Bunta

Comment: put `openOrCreateDatabase("myDatabase.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` in your Activity then you have database + folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse,On the upper right corner click DDMS, in File Explorer Section expand data--> data-->your app package name and here create new folder by click green plus button appearing on upper right corner, now name it data and push your db file in it.
[image]